# How to use EXPECT_CALL for private member?

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, googlemock

How to specify `EXPECT_CALL` for the private member?

My mocked private member is created in the constructor and calls function write. I get following warning:

> GMOCK WARNING:
>
> Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
>       Function call: write(0x1010, 1)

How to write `EXPECT_CALL` to disable warning?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class for making a expect call to write, the instance of this class should be created in the MainTestClass.

```
struct writeMock
{ // make an expect call to write here
};

struct MainTestClass : ::testing::Test
{
MainTestClass() {}

writeMock writeMock_;
// other members here
};
```

this is how your test suite will look like,

```
TEST_F(MainTestClass, TestCase1)
{
...
}
```